# How to determine who offered the second Korban Tamid of the day?

Tags: talmud-gemara, korban, mishna, masechet-yoma, maseches-tamid

The *mishnah* in [Tamid 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.3.1) and [Yoma 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.2.3) says there was a daily lottery for who would bring the (morning) Korban Tamid.
There was another Korban Tamid every day.

How was the person for the second Tamid selected? Was there a second lottery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gemara on [Yoma 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.26a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that there was just one lottery that covered both services:

> א"ר יוחנן אין מפייסין על תמיד של בין הערבים **אלא כהן שזכה בו בשחרית זוכה בו ערבית**
>
> Rabbi Yoḥanan said: They did not hold a separate lottery for the
> slaughtering and sacrifice of the daily afternoon offering. **Rather**,
> the same **priest who won** a particular privilege for **the morning**
> offering **wins** the privilege for the corresponding task in **the evening**,
> i.e., for the afternoon service.
>
> In this way, the morning lottery covered both services.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/1013256#v8

Comment: [related?](/q/7049/170)